# Should I drive control lines of an IC at voltages higher than VCC

Tags: boost, converter, level

I am designing a circuit that will be running from a single cell LiPo battery. The battery will provide the input voltage to a boost converter that will output 5V, which will power a microcontroller.

There are some control pins on the boost converter, such as PS, which enables power saving mode, as such I would like to be able to set PS high or low using my microcontroller, however, the micro will be providing 5v, and the boost converter is only running on the power supplied by the LiPo cell (~3.7v).

Does the voltage on PS need to be <= the voltage powering the boost converter, or can I safely push 5v into it without need needing to add a voltage level converter?

Comment: Datasheet says?

Comment: ^As Ignacio says in less words, the datasheet will tell you whether the input pins can handle 5V or not. Also, are your microcontroller outputs 5V? Sometimes micros are powered by 5V but have signals at 3.3V. In any case datasheets will tell you what you need to know. We'd just be guessing since you didn't provide the all important **part numbers**.

Comment: The boost converter is a TPS61200, 
http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/1853546.pdf

In the control stage table on page 3, Vih does not have a maximum rating. I thought it should say there if the max is a multiple of Vin, or 5.5v (max Vin). Any help would be appreciated.

I am driving it from an Arduino, which I believe outputs 5v on the IO lines

Comment: On page 1 it says it takes an input up to 5.5V. In the diagram on the bottom of the page it has that 5.5V input connected to PS. On page 2 it gives absolute maximum ratings for all pins. All input pins have max input of 7V. You're fine with 5V on that pin mate. I don't see any reason the input on PS would have to be a certain value in relation to Vin.

Comment: Lowering the voltage on the PS lead only requires a simple voltage divider (two resistors), so just do that, stop worrying and get on to something else.